# Create a table with mean duration times per years and types

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
library("lubridate")

df = data.frame(c("AAA","BBB","AAA"),
                c("2012","2013","2012"),
                c("2012-12-30 08:01:01","2013-12-30 09:05:02","2012-12-30 08:08:01"),
                c("2012-12-30 09:01:00","2013-12-30 10:15:00","2012-12-30 08:11:01"))
colnames(df) = c("type","year","start","end")

df$duration = difftime(ymd_hms(df$end), ymd_hms(df$start),units="mins")
```

Now I want to create a table with mean durations so that it would look as follows:

```
     2012   2013
AAA  31.49  0.00
BBB  0.00   69.97
```

Which functions should I use to create such table?

Update:

This is what I tried, but how can I add `year`?:

```
mean_duration_per_type_year = aggregate(duration~type,
                                        data=df,
                                        mean)
```

Comment: you could do it with the ``aggregate``function

Comment: @etienne: Not sure why the question was donwvoted. Anyway, I putted my current code. I am exactly using `aggregate`, however I have issues with htis function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do, using the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
temp <- aggregate(df$duration, by = list(type = df$type, year = df$year), mean)
final <- dcast(temp, type~year)
final[is.na(final)] <- 0 # optional : replace the NA values with 0


final
#   type     2012     2013
# 1  AAA 31.49167  0.00000
# 2  BBB  0.00000 69.96667
```

Note that if you want the type to be the rownames, you could add these lines:

```
rownames(final) <- final$type
final$type <- NULL

final
#         2012     2013
# AAA 31.49167  0.00000
# BBB  0.00000 69.96667
```